# Bit hack with NumPy

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, numpy, 32-bit

I was trying to implement the generalized version of the [fast inverse square root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root) that I found [here](http://h14s.p5r.org/2012/09/0x5f3759df.html) and this is what I came up with so far:

```
import numpy as np

def get_K(exponent, B=127, L=2**23, sigma=0.0450465, f=np.float32):
    return f((1 - exponent) * L * (B - f(sigma)))

def get_result(exponent, B=127, L=2**23, sigma=0.0450465, f=np.float32):
    K = f(get_K(exponent, 127, 2**23, f(0.0450465)))
    return lambda num: (K + f(num*exponent))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print((get_result(0.5)(2)).astype(np.int32))
```

but when I run the above example, I get `532487680`, which is the same result that I get in `numpy.float32` representation for `get_result(0.5)(2)`.

What am I doing wrong? In other words, how do I go from treating the number from a 32-bit floating point number to a 32-bit integer in the same way that I would in C, using numpy?

Comment: Use `.view(np.int32)` instead of `.astype(np.int32)`.

Comment: what answer are you expecting?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham  For the last statement of the script I expect the square root of two.

Comment: @Jaime thank you, I didn't know about that method. Still not getting the right result though, so it's possible I misinterpreted the formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following  fast inverse square root implementation could be used with numpy (adapted from [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root#Overview_of_the_code) ),

```
def fast_inv_sqrt(x):
    x = x.astype('float32')
    x2 = x * 0.5;
    y = x.view(dtype='int32')
    y = 0x5f3759df - np.right_shift(y, 1)
    y = y.view(dtype='float32')
    y  = y * ( 1.5 - ( x2 * y * y ) )
    return y
```

now since numpy would be allocating a number of temporary arrays this is not very fast,

```
 import numpy as np

 x = np.array(1,10000, dtype='float32')

 %timeit fast_inv_sqrt(x)
 # 10000 loops, best of 3: 36.2 µs per loop

 %timeit 1./np.sqrt(x)
 # 10000 loops, best of 3: 13.1 µs per loop
```

If you require speed, you should rather perform this calculation in C, and write a python interface using Cython, f2py, etc.